# How to remake the "brush" efftect used on this LOTR-Poster?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, filter

I am trying to remake a poster for a friends (nickname Frodo) wedding. I am close to finish, but I don't know how to give the resulat (it was more a less a simple face swap) the same brush-touch as the original.

[image: Frodo and the ring]

I tried to use photoshop-filters and paper/canvas overlays, but couldn't get a good result.

Thx, for your help!

Comment: Brush effect? Where? That simply looks like a low quality image.

Comment: @Scott, OK sorry I didn't thought this pattern are low quality image artefacts. For me it looks like, someone was trying to give it a more "painting" touch.

Comment: Pretty much blurry noise as far as I can see: duplicate the original photo layer, add noise with a filter, add gaussian blur using a filter, and lower the opacity of this duplicate layer if needed. Part of this look is also that it's mostly the dark parts that are noisy, which tracks because if you've ever taken a photo in the dark you know they can get pretty grainy, so you may want to lower the amount of noise in any well lit parts using a layer mask and a soft round brush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see there's in your image a slightly 3D-like noise texture which is masked so that lightest areas do not get the texture at all. I guess the noise layer has a layer mask which is the actual photo inverted. The noise oviously is blended with the photo is such way that it only darkens.

An example which uses that idea:

[image]

The noise texture is originally a solid grey which got Filter > Add Noise and Gaussian blur. The 3D-likeness was made with Filter > Stylize > Emboss. The contrast of the noise texture was stretched so that the lightest areas are white and the darkest are about 50% grey.

[image]

It's quite the same as Photoshop's Sandstone texture applied to a solid grey layer, this:

[image]

I guess the noise should be killed from the background if it has its own texture. I have transparent background. The noise texture has this layer mask which removes the noise from light areas and from the background:

[image]

It's the original hand but inverted and with increased contrast. You get the layer mask onscreen by clicking its icon in the Layers panel and by pressing Alt-key at the same time. I increased the contrast and made it negative at the same time with Image > Adjustments > Curves. The hand was pasted in place to the mask after the Alt+Click.

In the final image the noise layer has reduced opacity and blending mode Multiply.